# juju error executing lxc-clone local-provider

Tags: juju, lxc, owncloud-server

I'm trying to use juju with local-provider to setup juju-gui (and owncloud eventually).

After "juju deploy juju-gui", juju status shows the error:

```
agent-state-info: '(error: error executing "lxc-clone": lxc_container: failed
      mounting /var/lib/lxc/juju-precise-template/rootfs onto /var/lib/lxc/juju-precise-template/rootfs;
      lxc_container: Error copying storage; clone failed)'
```

I used the following commands:

```
juju init
juju switch local
juju bootstrap
juju deploy juju-gui
```

/var/lib/lxc/ is owned by root, so how can juju access it? Is anyone currently using juju 1.18 with local provider sucessfully?

I read that "sudo juju bootstrap" is not necessary anymore. So is juju using unprivileged lxc or planning on doing so?

I'm running juju version 1.18.0-trusty-amd64 inside a trusty lxc container.

Comment: Can you copy the `juju deploy --show-log --debug juju-gui`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The local provider does not work inside other lxc containers.  Nested lxc isn't supported without hacking the lxc config externally.